# How to split a bytearray or a bytes object into 16-bit integers?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, split

Given a `bytearray` object of length 2xN, how can I get a list (or an array) of N 16-bit integers from that object?

For example, if `ba` is defined as:

```
ba = bytearray([0x01, 0x02, 0x01, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff])
```

Then after conversion, the result shall be like:

```
ia = [0x0102, 0x0103, 0xffff]
print(ia[1]) ==> 0x0103
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `int.from_bytes` and a little list comprehension. Please note that `byte_order` needs to be specified, so you might have to change that depending on your application.

```
ba = bytearray([0x01, 0x02, 0x01, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff])
ia = [int.from_bytes(ba[i:i+2], "big") for i in range(0, len(ba), 2)]
```

Comment: Easy adaptation to my actual case of little-endian packing.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a big endian encoding (the first byte is the high bits). You can use the `struct` package. It uses a format string to describe the bytes coming from some iterable.

```
import struct
unpacker = struct.Struct(">H")
ba = bytearray([0x01, 0x02, 0x01, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff])
result =  [unpacked[0] for unpacked in unpacker.iter_unpack(ba)]
print([hex(r) for r in result])
```

The full set of endian specifiers is in the docs [Byte order, size and alignment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment).

Comment: Thanks. The example was big-endian indeed, but my actual case is little-endian.

Comment: @ysap - if you want little-endian, mention so in your question and show that in your example output. [0x0201, 0x0301, 0xffff]. Future visitors will appreciate it. (posted it on wrong answer a minute ago!).

Comment: Your answer answers the question as asked. The problem of endianness is secondary.